# A way to automate the creation of flashable ZIPs

Tags: recovery-mode, system-apps, zip

So, my question is: is there a way to automate the creation of flashable ZIP archives, in order to avoid having to write the **updater-script** and **update-binary** by myself each and every time I want a ZIP to be done?

Furthermore, the only feature the ZIP archives are required to do, is to install an application as **system app**. How could I perform such task, preferably without the aid of an external app?

Answer (score 1):

Being unable to find something that matched my needs, I resolved to write a little script by myself. It's open to anyone which needs it.

```
#!/system/bin/sh

#This variable is used to calculate the time took by the various operations
#Altering it will result in badly calculated elapsed time
SECONDS=0

#This variable saves the path where the script resides
#DO NOT ALTER IT, or the whole script will fail with unpredictable errors
scriptDir="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")"

#This function verifies if there's at least an APK in the script's folder
#///Beginning of function "apkChecker"///
function apkChecker {
 echo "[INFO] Checking if at least an APK file is present..."
 if [ "$(ls "$scriptDir" | grep "\.apk$")" != "$(cat /dev/null)" ]; then
  echo "[INFO] At least one APK file has been found."
 else
  echo "[FATAL] No APK file found. Aborting."
  exit
 fi
}
#///End of function "apkChecker"///

#This function checks if the required tools (aapt and zip) are installed
#///Beginning of function "depencenciesChecker"///
function dependenciesChecker {
 echo "[INFO] Checking if both the aapt and zip utilities are installed..."

 whence -v aapt &> /dev/null
 isAaptAbsent="$(echo $?)"

 whence -v zip &> /dev/null
 isZipAbsent="$(echo $?)"

 case "$isAaptAbsent" in
  0)
   case "$isZipAbsent" in
    0)
     echo "[INFO] Both aapt and zip have been found."
     unset "isAaptAbsent" "isZipAbsent"
     ;;
    *)
     echo "[FATAL] zip cannot be found. Aborting."
     exit
     ;;
   esac
   ;;
  *)
   case "$isZipAbsent" in
    0)
     echo "[FATAL] aapt cannot be found. Aborting."
     exit
     ;;
    *)
     echo "[FATAL] Neither aapt nor zip can be found. Aborting."
     exit
     ;;
   esac
   ;;
 esac
}
#///End of function "dependenciesChecker"///

#This function relies on aapt, and is meant to retrieve the app's name from the given APK
#Notice that only the first APK in a list gets picked
#///Beginning of function "appNameRetriever"///
function appNameRetriever {
 echo "[INFO] Retrieving app name from the provided APK..."
 apkFile="$(ls "$scriptDir" | grep "\.apk$" | head -n 1)"
 appName="$(aapt d badging "$scriptDir"/"$apkFile")"
 appName="${appName#*application-label:\'}"
 appName="${appName//app*/}"
 appName="${appName%\'*}"
 displayedName=$appName
 appName="$(printf "%s" $appName)"
}
#///End of function "appNameRetriever"///

#This function creates the tree used by the ZIP (namely, the META-INF/com/google/android and appName folders)
#It also copies the previously picked APK to the appName folder, renaming it in the process
#///Beginning of function "folderTreeCreator"///
function folderTreeCreator {
 echo "[INFO] Creating ZIP folder tree and placing the APK to be flashed inside it..."
 mkdir -p ""$scriptDir"/$appName/META-INF/com/google/android"
 mkdir -p ""$scriptDir"/$appName/$appName"
 cp ""$scriptDir"/""$apkFile""" ""$scriptDir"/$appName/$appName/$appName.apk"
}
#///End of function "folderTreeCreator"///

#This function creates a dummy updater-script, which server mainly for aesthetical purposes
#///Beginning of function "updaterScriptCreator"///
function updaterScriptCreator {
 echo "[INFO] Creating dummy updater-script..."
 echo -n "#This is a dummy file. The magic is in the update-binary, which is a shell script." > ""$scriptDir"/$appName/META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script"
}
#///End of function "updaterScriptCreator"///

#=== BEGINNING OF "update-binary" WRITING SECTION ===
#From now on, the functions whose name begins with "sectionWriter", are used to assemble the update-binary

#This function writes the function and variables used for outputting things when flashing, to update-binary
#Thanks to Chainfire @ XDA, which seems to have been the first to implement them
#///Beginning of function "sectionWriter_header"///
function sectionWriter_header {
 echo "[INFO] Writing variables and functions prototypes to update-binary..."
 cat <<-EOF > ""$scriptDir"/$appName/META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary"
#!/sbin/sh

OUTFD=\$2
ZIP=\$3

ui_print() {
 echo -ne "ui_print \$1\n" > /proc/self/fd/\$OUTFD
 echo -ne "ui_print\n" > /proc/self/fd/\$OUTFD
}

EOF
}
#///End of function "sectionWriter_header"///

#This function writes the title of the ZIP (which contains the human-readable app name of the APK), to update-binary
#///Beginning of function "sectionWriter_zipName"///
function sectionWriter_zipName {
 echo "[INFO] Writing script title to update-binary..."
 cat << EOF >> ""$scriptDir"/$appName/META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary"
ui_print ""
ui_print "******************************"
ui_print " $displayedName Flashable ZIP "
ui_print " made by EDGAR, written by "
ui_print " Death Mask Salesman "
ui_print "******************************"
ui_print ""

EOF
}
#///End of function "sectionWriter_zipName"///

#This function writes the instructions necessary to mount the system partition in read-write mode, to update-binary
#///Beginning of function "sectionWriter_systemRwMount"///
function sectionWriter_systemRwMount {
 echo "[INFO] Writing mount instructions to update-binary..."
 cat << EOF >> ""$scriptDir"/$appName/META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary"
ui_print "~ Mounting /system in read-write mode..."
mount /system
mount -o remount,rw /system
ui_print ""

EOF
}
#///End of function "sectionWriter_systemRwMount"///

#This function writes the instructions to check for the Android version, to update-binary
#Notice that only JB, KK, LP and MM are supported, for now. That means a vast plethora of devices
#///Beginning of function "sectionWriter_osVersionChecker"///
function sectionWriter_osVersionChecker {
 echo "[INFO] Writing OS checking instructions to update-binary..."
 cat << EOF >> ""$scriptDir"/$appName/META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary"
ui_print "~ Checking Android version..."
androidVersion="\$(cat /system/build.prop | grep 'ro\.build\.version\.release')"
androidVersion="\${androidVersion#*=}"

case "\$androidVersion" in
 4.1*|4.1.*|4.2*|4.2.*|4.3*|4.3.*)
  ui_print "~ Android Jelly Bean (\$androidVersion) detected: proceeding."
  ;;
 4.4*|4.4.*)
  ui_print "~ Android KitKat (\$androidVersion) detected: proceeding."
  ;;
 5*|5.*|5.*.*)
  ui_print "~ Android Lollipop (\$androidVersion) detected: proceeding."
  ;;
 6*|6.*|6.*.*)
  ui_print "~ Android Marshmallow (\$androidVersion) detected: proceeding."
  ;;
 *)
  ui_print "~ Your Android version (\$androidVersion) is either obsolete or still unsupported."
  ui_print "~ Unmounting /system and aborting."
  umount /system
  exit
  ;;
esac

EOF
}
#///End of function "sectionWriter_osVersionChecker"///

#This function writes the instructions needed to unpack the ZIP to a temporary location, to update-binary
#This procedure is needed to obtain the APK to be installed as system app
#///Beginning of function "sectionWriter_zipUnpacker"///
function sectionWriter_zipUnpacker {
 echo "[INFO] Writing ZIP unpacking instructions to update-binary..."
 cat << EOF >> ""$scriptDir"/$appName/META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary"
ui_print "~ Extracting the ZIP to a temporary folder..."
mkdir -p "/tmp/$appName"
cd "/tmp/$appName"
unzip -o "\$ZIP"
ui_print ""

EOF
}
#///End of function "sectionWriter_zipUnpacker"///

#This function writes the bunch of instructions necessary to install the app as system, to update-binary
#As can be seen from the case-esac, almost each Android release has its specific install location
#///Beginning of function "sectionWriter_appInstaller"///
function sectionWriter_appInstaller {
 echo "[INFO] Writing APK installation instructions to update-binary..."
 cat << EOF >> ""$scriptDir"/$appName/META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary"
ui_print "~ Installing $displayedName..."

case "\$androidVersion" in
 4.1*|4.1.*|4.2*|4.2.*|4.3*|4.3.*)
  cp "/tmp/$appName/$appName/$appName.apk" "/system/app/"
  ;;
 4.4*|4.4.*)
  cp "/tmp/$appName/$appName/$appName.apk" "/system/priv-app/"
  ;;
 5*|5.*|5.*.*|6*|6.*|6.*.*)
  mkdir -p "/system/priv-app/$appName"
  cp "/tmp/$appName/$appName/$appName.apk" "/system/priv-app/$appName/"
  ;;
esac

ui_print "~ $displayedName has been installed."
ui_print ""

EOF
}
#///End of function "sectionWriter_appInstaller"///

#This function writes the instructions to change ownership, permissions and eventual SELinux context, to update-binary
#As for now, the script determines if SELinux is present by looking for the setenforce binary
#I'll probably base the check on the presence of "/sys/fs/selinux", but that has to be done in a next version 
#///Beginning of function "sectionWriter_validateApp"///
function sectionWriter_validateApp {
 echo "[INFO] Writing APK ownership, permission and context change instructions to update-binary..."
 cat << EOF >> ""$scriptDir"/$appName/META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary"
case "\$androidVersion" in
 4.1*|4.2*|4.3*)
  ui_print "~ Setting ownership and permissions..."
  chown 0.0 "/system/app/$appName.apk"
  chmod 644 "/system/app/$appName.apk"
  if [ -e "/system/bin/setenforce" ]; then
   ui_print "~ Setting SELinux appropriate context..."
   chcon u:object_r:system_file:s0 "/system/app/$appName.apk"
  fi
  ;;
 4.4*)
  ui_print "~ Setting ownership and permissions..."
  chown 0.0 "/system/priv-app/$appName.apk"
  chmod 644 "/system/priv-app/$appName.apk"
  if [ -e "/system/bin/setenforce" ]; then
   ui_print "~ Setting SELinux appropriate context..."
   chcon u:object_r:system_file:s0 "/system/priv-app/$appName.apk"
  fi
  ;;
 5*|6*)
  ui_print "~ Setting ownership and permissions..."
  chown 0.0 "/system/priv-app/$appName"
  chmod 755 "/system/priv-app/$appName"
  chown 0.0 "/system/priv-app/$appName/$appName.apk"
  chmod 644 "/system/priv-app/$appName/$appName.apk"
  if [ -e "/system/bin/setenforce" ]; then
   ui_print "~ Setting SELinux appropriate context..."
   chcon u:object_r:system_file:s0 "/system/priv-app/$appName"
   chcon u:object_r:system_file:s0 "/system/priv-app/$appName/$appName.apk"
  fi
  ;;
esac
ui_print ""

EOF
}
#///End of function "sectionWriter_validateApp"///

#This function writes the instructions to unmount the system partition, to update-binary
#///Beginning of function "sectionWriter_systemUnmount"///
function sectionWriter_systemUnmount {
 echo "[INFO] Writing unmount instructions to update-binary..."
 cat << EOF >> ""$scriptDir"/$appName/META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary"
ui_print "~ Unmounting /system..."
umount /system
ui_print ""

EOF
}
#///End of function "sectionWriter_systemUnmount"///

#This function writes something as a termination/goodbye message, to update-binary
#///Beginning of function "sectionWriter_goodbyeString"///
function sectionWriter_goodbyeString {
 echo "[INFO] Writing goodbye message to update-binary..."
 echo "ui_print \"Installation completed! Have a great day!\"" >> ""$scriptDir"/$appName/META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary"
}
#///End of function "sectionWriter_goodbyeString"///

#=== END OF "update-binary" WRITING SECTION ===

#This function packs the META-INF and appName folders, thus creating the flashable ZIP
#DO NOT set a compression level of "0", or the produced ZIP will be corrupted
#///Beginning of function "zipPacker"///
function zipPacker {
 echo "[INFO] Packing the ZIP..."

 cd ""$scriptDir"/$appName"
 zip -qr9 $appName.zip *
}
#///End of function "zipPacker"///

#This function moves the compressed ZIP to the same directory of the script, and wipes the directories created by "folderTreeCreator", along with their content
#///Beginning of function "cleanup"///
function cleanup {
 echo "[INFO] Moving the flashable ZIP to "$scriptDir"..."
 mv ""$scriptDir"/$appName/$appName.zip" "$scriptDir"

 echo "[INFO] Cleaning up the folders used as ZIP base..."
 rm -rf ""$scriptDir"/$appName"
}
#///End of function "cleanup"///

#This is the core of the EDGAR tool
#Here, all of the previously defined functions are called in the correct order
#To add a function, and thus extend EDGAR's versatility, simply define it above, and call it below
#///Beginning of EDGAR's core///
echo "**************************************"
echo " EDGAR - Flashable ZIP creator script "
echo "    by    Death    Mask    Salesman   "
echo "**************************************"
echo ""

apkChecker
echo ""

dependenciesChecker
echo ""

appNameRetriever
echo ""

folderTreeCreator
echo ""

updaterScriptCreator
echo ""

sectionWriter_header
sectionWriter_zipName
sectionWriter_systemRwMount
sectionWriter_osVersionChecker
sectionWriter_zipUnpacker
sectionWriter_appInstaller
sectionWriter_validateApp
sectionWriter_systemUnmount
sectionWriter_goodbyeString
echo ""

zipPacker
echo ""

cleanup
echo ""

echo "[INFO] Operations took "$(((SECONDS/60)/60))" hours, "$(((SECONDS/60)%60))" minutes and "$((SECONDS%60))" seconds."
echo "[INFO] All done!"
#///End of EDGAR's core///
```

Comment: Why did you make this a wiki? Do you realize that its content is opened to alteration?

Comment: @Firelord I do realize it fully. I decided to make it a wiki because I would like users to add their own modifications (should them be needed), fixes et similia. Secondly, it's not fair for me to steal reputation for something I coded and published by exploiting a loophole in the rules, even if it may be useful to others.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman It's not really about stealing reputation. The reputation is just a reward for good efforts you have made. If you want someone to correct or improve script, they can edit normally. It would most probably get approved anyway

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman can you explain more about how to use this please?  I don't understand where it runs and how it's used? Can you provide an example of its use please? (from the shebang path I guess it runs on an Android device?) Also, does it cater for multiple `.apk` packages and does it cater for such packages that contain native libraries?

Comment: @starfry It is to be ran from a rooted Android device. Assume that its location is the root directory of the internal storage. You will need to place your APK of choice in the same directory of the script, then open a Terminal and issue `su`. Next, `cd` to `/data/media/0`, assign the correct permissions with `chmod 777 ./script_name.sh`, where `script_name` is the name you assigned to a file with the content in this answer. To successfully build a flashable ZIP, your device will **need** to have both the **aapt** and **zip** binaries installed. Once the conditions are met, run the script...

Comment: @starfry ... with `./script_name.sh`. The script (**EDGAR**) will create the structure of the flashable ZIP, write the **updater-script** and the **update-binary**, copy the APK in the appropriate folder of the ZIP, compress the actual ZIP and move it to the script's directory and wipe the raw folders it created in the process. *The script can (as of now) create flashable ZIPs of standalone APK files; no libraries. The ZIP per se may be flashed on Android devices from 4.1.x to 6.0.x (could not test Android N): its* **update-binary** *will take care of all the permissions and SELinux contexts.*

Comment: Well that worked first time! I'm going to take a litle time to understand it and then hopefully produce a version that handles multiple ZIPS and installs any libraries in the correct place. I'll let you know how I get on.

Comment: @starfry Glad it worked, and please keep me updated about your progress. Maybe I'll rewrite this one, in the meantime.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman I have it running on Linux (once I got `aapt` [installed](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/156520)). Only change was to shebang (`/bin/sh`) and to use `which` instead of `whence`. Tomorrow I will try to make it multi-package but that's enough for today!

Answer (score 1):

I have taken the script by @DeathMaskSalesman and augmented it so that it produces a ZIP containing all `.apk` packages found in the current directory and installs both those packages as well as the libraries contained therein.

```
#!/bin/sh
#!/system/bin/sh
# Swap the above two lines as appropriate: Linux: /bin/sh; Android: /system/bin/sh
#http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/143304

#This variable is used to calculate the time took by the various operations
#Altering it will result in badly calculated elapsed time
SECONDS=0

#This variable saves the path where the script resides
#DO NOT ALTER IT, or the whole script will fail with unpredictable errors
scriptDir="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")"

# This defines the name of the created ZIP
ZIPFILE="$scriptDir/edgar.zip"

# This defines the name of the temporary directory where
# the ZIP structure will be built
ZIPDIR="$ZIPFILE.dir"

rm -rf "$ZIPDIR" "$ZIPFILE" # Uncomment to automatically remove pre-existing ZIP

#This defines the path to the update-binary within the ZIPDIR
UPDATE_BINARY="$ZIPDIR/META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary"

#Helper function to abort: prints fatal error message and exits
abort() { echo '[FATAL] '$*; exit 1; }

#Aborts unless listed dependencies are satisfied
depend() {
  for dep in "$@"
  do  
    which "${dep}" &> /dev/null || \
      abort 'Missing dependency '${dep}' (required: '$@')'
  done
}

#This function relies on aapt, and is meant to retrieve the app's name from the given APK
#///Beginning of function "appNameRetriever"///
#Sets globals $displayedName to the app name with whitespace intact
#             $appName to the app name with whitespace removed
#             $apkFile to the path passed in as $1
function appNameRetriever {
 echo "[INFO] Retrieving app name from $1..."
 apkFile="$1"
 appName="$(aapt d badging "$apkFile")"
 appName="${appName#*application-label:\'}"
 appName="${appName//app*/}"
 appName="${appName%\'*}"
 displayedName=$appName
 appName="$(printf "%s" $appName)"
}
#///End of function "appNameRetriever"///

#This function creates the directory structure required inside ZIP
init() {
  [[ -e "$1" ]] && abort "Cannot initialize '$1'; already exists"
  echo "[INFO] Initializing ZIP structure..."
  mkdir -p "$ZIPDIR/META-INF/com/google/android"
}
#///End of function "folderTreeCreator"///

add_apk() {
 echo "[INFO] Adding $appName..." 
 mkdir -p "$ZIPDIR/$appName"
 cp "$apkFile" "$ZIPDIR/$appName/$appName.apk"
}

#This function creates a dummy updater-script, which serves mainly for aesthetical purposes
#///Beginning of function "updaterScriptCreator"///
function updaterScriptCreator {
 echo "[INFO] Creating dummy updater-script..."
 echo -n "#This is a dummy file. The magic is in the update-binary, which is a shell script." > "$ZIPDIR/META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script"
}
#///End of function "updaterScriptCreator"///

#=== BEGINNING OF "update-binary" WRITING SECTION ===
#From now on, the functions whose name begins with "sectionWriter", are used to assemble the update-binary

#This function writes the function and variables used for outputting things when flashing, to update-binary
#Thanks to Chainfire @ XDA, which seems to have been the first to implement them
#///Beginning of function "sectionWriter_header"///
function sectionWriter_header {
 echo "[INFO] Writing variables and function prototypes to update-binary..."
 cat <<-EOF > "$ZIPDIR/META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary"
#!/sbin/sh

OUTFD=\$2
ZIP=\$3

ui_print() {
 echo -ne "ui_print \$1\n" > /proc/self/fd/\$OUTFD
 echo -ne "ui_print\n" > /proc/self/fd/\$OUTFD
}

get_buildprop() {
 prop=\$(grep "\${1//./\\.}=" /system/build.prop)
 echo "\${prop#*=}"
}

ui_print ""
ui_print "******************************"
ui_print " APK Flashable ZIP "
ui_print " made by EDGAR, written by "
ui_print " Death Mask Salesman "
ui_print "******************************"
ui_print ""
EOF
}
#///End of function "sectionWriter_header"///

#This function writes the title of the app (which contains the human-readable app name of the APK), to update-binary
#///Beginning of function "sectionWriter_zipName"///
function sectionWriter_appName {
 echo "[INFO] Writing script title to update-binary..."
 cat << EOF >> "$ZIPDIR/META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary"
ui_print ""
ui_print "******************************"

EOF
}
#///End of function "sectionWriter_zipName"///

#This function writes the instructions necessary to mount the system partition in read-write mode, to update-binary
#///Beginning of function "sectionWriter_systemRwMount"///
function sectionWriter_systemRwMount {
 echo "[INFO] Writing mount instructions to update-binary..."
 cat << EOF >> "$ZIPDIR/META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary"
ui_print "~ Mounting /system in read-write mode..."
mount /system
mount -o remount,rw /system
ui_print ""

EOF
}
#///End of function "sectionWriter_systemRwMount"///

#This function writes the instructions to check for the Android version, to update-binary
#Notice that only JB, KK, LP and MM are supported, for now. That means a vast plethora of devices
#///Beginning of function "sectionWriter_osVersionChecker"///
function sectionWriter_osVersionChecker {
 echo "[INFO] Writing OS checking instructions to update-binary..."
 cat << EOF >> "$ZIPDIR/META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary"
ui_print "~ Checking Android version..."
androidVersion="\$(get_buildprop 'ro.build.version.release')"

case "\$androidVersion" in
 4.1*|4.1.*|4.2*|4.2.*|4.3*|4.3.*)
  ui_print "~ Android Jelly Bean (\$androidVersion) detected: proceeding."
  ;;
 4.4*|4.4.*)
  ui_print "~ Android KitKat (\$androidVersion) detected: proceeding."
  ;;
 5*|5.*|5.*.*)
  ui_print "~ Android Lollipop (\$androidVersion) detected: proceeding."
  ;;
 6*|6.*|6.*.*)
  ui_print "~ Android Marshmallow (\$androidVersion) detected: proceeding."
  ;;
 *)
  ui_print "~ Your Android version (\$androidVersion) is either obsolete or still unsupported."
  ui_print "~ Unmounting /system and aborting."
  umount /system
  ;;
esac

EOF
}
#///End of function "sectionWriter_osVersionChecker"///

#This function gets the list of supported ABI versions (CPU Architecture)
#in increasing order of preference
#///Beginning of function "sectionWriter_getAbiList
function sectionWriter_getAbiList {
  echo "[INFO] Writing getAbi instructions to update-binary..."
  cat << EOF >> "$UPDATE_BINARY"
ui_print "~ Getting supported ABIs..."

reverse() {
  if [ "\$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    local arg=\$1
    shift
    reverse "\$@"
    echo -n "\$arg "
  fi
}

androidAbiList="\$(get_buildprop 'ro.product.cpu.abilist')"
androidAbiList="\${androidAbiList//,/ }"
if [[ -n "\$androidAbiList" ]]
then
  androidAbiList="\$(reverse \$androidAbiList)"
else
  androidAbi="\$(get_buildprop 'ro.product.cpu.abi')"
  androidAbi2="\$(get_buildprop 'ro.product.cpu.abi2')"
  androidAbiList="\$androidAbi2 \$androidAbi"
fi

ui_print "~ Supported ABIs: \$androidAbiList"

EOF
}
#///End of function "sectionWriter_osVersionChecker"///

#This function writes the bunch of instructions necessary to install the app as system, to update-binary
#As can be seen from the case-esac, almost each Android release has its specific install location
#///Beginning of function "sectionWriter_apkInstaller"///
function sectionWriter_apkInstaller {
 echo "[INFO] Writing APK installation instructions to update-binary..."
 cat << EOF >> "$ZIPDIR/META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary"
ui_print "~ Installing $displayedName..."

case "\$androidVersion" in
 4.1*|4.1.*|4.2*|4.2.*|4.3*|4.3.*)
  unzip -qo "\$ZIP" '$appName/$appName.apk' -d '/system/app/'
  ;;
 4.4*|4.4.*)
  unzip -qo "\$ZIP" '$appName/$appName.apk' -d '/system/priv-app/'
  ;;
 5*|5.*|5.*.*|6*|6.*|6.*.*)
  unzip -qo "\$ZIP" '$appName/*' -d '/system/priv-app'
  ;;
esac

ui_print "~ $displayedName has been installed."
ui_print ""

EOF
}
#///End of function "sectionWriter_apkInstaller"///

#This function writes instructions to update-binary to install any libs in the apk
#As can be seen from the case-esac, almost each Android release has its specific install location
#///Beginning of function "sectionWriter_libInstaller"///
function sectionWriter_libInstaller {
 echo "[INFO] Writing library installation instructions to update-binary..."
 cat << EOF >> "$ZIPDIR/META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary"
ui_print "~ Installing $displayedName libraries..."

case "\$androidVersion" in
 4.1*|4.1.*|4.2*|4.2.*|4.3*|4.3.*|4.4*|4.4.*)
  apkFile='/system/app/$appName/$appName.apk'
  ;;
 5*|5.*|5.*.*|6*|6.*|6.*.*)
  apkFile='/system/priv-app/$appName/$appName.apk'
  ;;
esac

unzip -qo "\$apkFile" 'lib/*'
for abi in \$androidAbiList
do
  if [[ -d "lib/\$abi" ]]
  then
    ui_print "~ \$abi..."
    mv lib/\$abi/* '/system/vendor/lib'
  fi
done
rm -rf lib

ui_print "~ $displayedName libs have been installed."
ui_print ""

EOF
}
#///End of function "sectionWriter_libInstaller"///

#This function writes the instructions to change ownership, permissions and eventual SELinux context, to update-binary
#As for now, the script determines if SELinux is present by looking for the setenforce binary
#I'll probably base the check on the presence of "/sys/fs/selinux", but that has to be done in a next version 
#///Beginning of function "sectionWriter_validateApp"///
function sectionWriter_validateApp {
 echo "[INFO] Writing APK ownership, permission and context change instructions to update-binary..."
 cat << EOF >> "$ZIPDIR/META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary"
case "\$androidVersion" in
 4.1*|4.2*|4.3*)
  ui_print "~ Setting ownership and permissions..."
  chown 0.0 "/system/app/$appName.apk"
  chmod 644 "/system/app/$appName.apk"
  if [ -e "/system/bin/setenforce" ]; then
   ui_print "~ Setting SELinux appropriate context..."
   chcon u:object_r:system_file:s0 "/system/app/$appName.apk"
  fi
  ;;
 4.4*)
  ui_print "~ Setting ownership and permissions..."
  chown 0.0 "/system/priv-app/$appName.apk"
  chmod 644 "/system/priv-app/$appName.apk"
  if [ -e "/system/bin/setenforce" ]; then
   ui_print "~ Setting SELinux appropriate context..."
   chcon u:object_r:system_file:s0 "/system/priv-app/$appName.apk"
  fi
  ;;
 5*|6*)
  ui_print "~ Setting ownership and permissions..."
  chown 0.0 "/system/priv-app/$appName"
  chmod 755 "/system/priv-app/$appName"
  chown 0.0 "/system/priv-app/$appName/$appName.apk"
  chmod 644 "/system/priv-app/$appName/$appName.apk"
  if [ -e "/system/bin/setenforce" ]; then
   ui_print "~ Setting SELinux appropriate context..."
   chcon u:object_r:system_file:s0 "/system/priv-app/$appName"
   chcon u:object_r:system_file:s0 "/system/priv-app/$appName/$appName.apk"
  fi
  ;;
esac
ui_print ""

EOF
}
#///End of function "sectionWriter_validateApp"///

#This function writes the instructions to unmount the system partition, to update-binary
#///Beginning of function "sectionWriter_systemUnmount"///
function sectionWriter_systemUnmount {
 echo "[INFO] Writing unmount instructions to update-binary..."
 cat << EOF >> "$UPDATE_BINARY"
ui_print "~ Unmounting /system..."
umount /system
ui_print ""

EOF
}
#///End of function "sectionWriter_systemUnmount"///

#This function writes something as a termination/goodbye message, to update-binary
#///Beginning of function "sectionWriter_goodbyeString"///
function sectionWriter_goodbyeString {
 echo "[INFO] Writing goodbye message to update-binary..."
 echo "ui_print \"Installation completed! Have a great day!\"" >> "$UPDATE_BINARY"
}
#///End of function "sectionWriter_goodbyeString"///

#=== END OF "update-binary" WRITING SECTION ===

#This function packs the prepared ZIP directory and
#removes it, leaving behind the flashable ZIP
#DO NOT set a compression level of "0", or the produced ZIP will be corrupted
#///Beginning of function "zipPacker"///
function zipPacker {
 echo "[INFO] Packing the ZIP..."

 OLDPWD=$(pwd)
 cd "$ZIPDIR"
 zip -qr9 "$ZIPFILE" .
 cd "$OLDPWD"
 rm -rf "$ZIPDIR"
}
#///End of function "zipPacker"///

#This is the core of the EDGAR tool
#Here, all of the previously defined functions are called in the correct order
#To add a function, and thus extend EDGAR's versatility, simply define it above, and call it below
#///Beginning of EDGAR's core///
echo "**************************************"
echo " EDGAR - Flashable ZIP creator script "
echo "    by    Death    Mask    Salesman   "
echo "**************************************"
echo ""

depend aapt zip find
echo ""

init "$ZIPDIR"
echo ""

updaterScriptCreator
echo ""

sectionWriter_header
sectionWriter_systemRwMount
sectionWriter_osVersionChecker
sectionWriter_getAbiList

for appName in $( find "$scriptDir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.apk' )
do
  appNameRetriever "$appName"
  sectionWriter_appName
  add_apk
  sectionWriter_apkInstaller
  sectionWriter_libInstaller
  sectionWriter_validateApp
done

sectionWriter_systemUnmount
sectionWriter_goodbyeString
echo ""

zipPacker
echo ""

echo "[INFO] Operations took "$(((SECONDS/60)/60))" hours, "$(((SECONDS/60)%60))" minutes and "$((SECONDS%60))" seconds."
echo "[INFO] All done!"
#///End of EDGAR's core///
```

Some points

- The script runs on my Android Lollipop and on Linux. I haven't been able to test on other Android versions.
- I have only tested flashing the generated ZIP using FlashFire.
- It installs libraries for the ABI that the Android system reports as valid. Where there are multiple it installs all of them from the least preferable to the most preferable (so the latter overwrites the former).

I am just learning about the internals of Android and I may have done some things incorrectly, so bear that in mind when looking at the script. I think the script could do with some cleaning up but I just wanted to get it out there for @DeathMaskSalesman to take a look at.

Comment: Seems pretty good, I'd say. I'll test it when my other script, NEMRIS, will be the way I want it! And kudos for making it runnable under Linux with minimal effort.

Comment: Hi @DeathMaskSalesman, I have made some amendments to my script to support installs to both `/system/app` and `/system/priv-app` and to support injection of custom commands around the install (for example, to wipe unwanted stock apps). I've pushed my [latest version](https://github.com/johnlane/android_apkzip)  onto GitHub